# HTML to grab new data on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, refresh

I have an HTML page with JavaScript that reads a JSON file and renders some data on the screen based on this JSON file. I need to refresh this page periodically (every 10 seconds) so that it captures changes from the JSON file. I am doing the following :

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2" />
```

I also tried doing this with the following code within my Java script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout("location.reload(true);",2000);
```

Both the versions work and refresh the page periodically. However, whenever a refresh happens, it does not read the new data from my JSON file. It only reads the data when I manually refresh the page using "Refresh" button. Is there any way I can force it to read the new data when it refreshes?

Comment: Have you considered have an external page that fetches the data from the csv and doing ajax calls to that? (similiar to an API)

Comment: Have you be able to set expires header of the CSV file? If yes, set it to the past. You can also use something like http://your.url/file.csv?r=[insert_current_timestamp]

Comment: not too familiar with AJAX.. How would I go about that..

Comment: Are you familiar with php?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, folks. Its a Json file that has my inputs, not a csv.

Comment: JQuery example of ajax: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ok using JQuery create a second page that with this html, and set the `url` var to the page you are currently hitting. If you hit the new page it should refresh with data every 10 seconds.

```
<div id="div1">
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = //path to your page that is currently working
  reloadData = function() {
    $.ajax({url: url, success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result); //takes the content of your url and throws it into div1
    }});
  }
  window.setInterval(reloadData, 10000);//every 10 seconds
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just added the url var in the ajax call... so if you already copied the code make that update

Comment: This works, but it also does not catch the new content from my JSON file. It keeps displaying the old data, till I hit refresh manually. I need it to take the new data, every time a refresh is done.